# Is a question containing an on-topic portion and an off-topic portion allowed?

Tags: discussion

I'm referring to this question:

[What is this percussion instrument that produces the shaky sound?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/24721/6851)

At first glance, this question is off-topic, because instrument identification questions are [explicitly off topic](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) per the FAQ.

However, the second part of the question is on-topic:

> And could I produce the same sound with my maracas? I'm not sure if I'm just not skilled enough with the maracas or I need to buy a separate instrument for that.

Despite the off-topic sounding title, this second part of the question is really the important part of the question, but the asker needed to ask the first part, because he didn't know what to call the instrument.

Is this question allowed?  Does it need to be edited, or perhaps just the title needs to be edited, to remain open on this site?

Comment: Apologies - looks like I'd already gone and edited the title in between this meta post being made, and being linked in the comments! I think it's got enough on-topic content to stand, hence my edit to make the title better reflect the question content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I retracted my close vote, because, like you said, at first glance it is off topic but now that I re-read it, it is not.

I edited the title to make it a bit more clear that OP is not *just* looking for the name of the instrument, but for a way to replicate its sound.

When the question was first posted, titled

> What is this percussion instrument that produces the shaky sound?

it looked like it was off topic.